# Images does not load on first load

Tags: magento-2.1

When I enter my Magento website, Most of the time, some images do not load 
(Sometimes they do load).

However, when I refresh the page, all the images become visible.

Please suggest how can I debug this Problem?

Comment: share your site url , may be you have some console error or something kind of thing.

Comment: please share your code where you have defined your js code for slider

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya sorry! which slider?

Comment: Can't you see all the css, js code in web inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging js on admin panel solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by disable the lazy load setting from admin .For this Navigate to **Store->configuration->Porto setting panel->Speed Optimization Setting**->Disable Lazyload for Product Images to **yes**.